# Pick Date Range, Count multiple Records in range based off condition, group by shift

Tags: sql, count, subquery

So I am new to SQL World, so please forgive how ignorant this question might be. I will likely need to do a stored procedure for this eventually but trying to get it to work in a query before I go to the next step.

I am attempting to do the following:

1. Select Records between certain dates
2. Count the records given a condition  in the where statement. I have 6 different records to count, that will require a new column for each count.
3. I then want to Group by A or B

I can count the records like so below.

```
     SELECT        (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS 6F
                      FROM            dbo.1_Data
                      WHERE        ([B] BETWEEN 1 AND 9) AND (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                                '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102))) AS 6F,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS 5E
                           FROM            dbo.1_Data AS 1_Data_1
                           WHERE        ([B] = 10) AND (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00',
                                                      102))) AS 5E,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS 4D
                           FROM            dbo.1_Data AS 1_Data_2
                           WHERE        ([B] BETWEEN 11 AND 13) AND (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                                     '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102))) AS 4D,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS 1A
                           FROM            dbo.1_Data AS 1_Data_3
                           WHERE        ([B] = 14) AND (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00',
                                                      102))) AS 1A,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS 2B
                           FROM            dbo.1_Data AS 1_Data_4
                           WHERE        ([A Step] BETWEEN 1 AND 25) AND (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                                     '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102))) AS 2B,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS 3C
                           FROM            dbo.1_Data AS 1_Data_5
                           WHERE        ([B Step] = 0) AND ([ A Step] = 0) AND (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND 
                                                     CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102))) AS 3C
```

I can do this to get number of records in a given step during a time range and grouped.

```
    SELECT COUNT([B]) AS [1A], Letter

    FROM  dbo.1_Data

    WHERE (Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-05 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-10 00:00:00', 102)) AND ([B] = 14)

    GROUP BY Letter
```

I am looking for final results to look something similar to this. With Column name on top, and the count of records down below that.

Column of 1A, with count of Records for A and count for B.

|1A | Letter |

---

|34 | A |

---

|93 | B |

How can I merge all of this into one query statement, to get me data sorted out, within a given date range and condition, then grouped by letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still confused what you want but I think you need this

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ( [B] BETWEEN 1 AND 9 )
                       AND ( [Time] BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' ) THEN 1
                  ELSE NULL
             END) AS '6f'
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ( [B] = 10 )
                        AND ( [Time] BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' ) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS '5E'
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ( [B] BETWEEN 11 AND 13 )
                        AND ( [Time] BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' ) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS '4D'
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ( [B] = 14 )
                        AND ( [Time] BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' ) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS '1A'
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ( [A Step] BETWEEN 1 AND 25 )
                        AND ( [Time] BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' ) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS '2B'
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN [B Step] = 0
                        AND [ A Step] = 0
                        AND ( [Time] BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' ) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS '3C'
    FROM dbo.[1_Data]
```

- You do not need to convert '2014-01-01' to `DATETIME` SQL Server will do that automatically
- You can place logic inside `CASE` statement and `COUNT` results of `CASE` statement,when counting remember to `NULL` your else results otherwise it will count everything.

Comment: That worked. I was hoping to have a way to only need to change the StartDate and EndDate once. But I can address that with parameters in stored procedure.

Thank you for the help. I have marked your reply has answered.

Comment: Nevermind. My mistake. This will work perfect with the proper where statement in there. Thank you again for helping figure this out.